# Django Project parsing parameters in request

Tags: python, django, extjs, django-rest-framework

I have request to my django project from ExtJS application:

```
GET /products/?page=1&start=0&limit=25&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22DESC%22%7D%5D
```

At the request contains 4 parameters, one of which is a complex, which is called **sort**:

[image: screen]

Question: how to extract the values of the parameters **property** and **direction** using Python?

I did so, but it does not work. I would be glad of any help.

```python
class ProductsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Products.objects.all()
        sortParameter = self.request.query_params.get('sort', None)
        column_name=sortParameter['property']
        queryset = queryset.order_by(column_name)
        return queryset
```

If you know the best way to sort and filter the data on the server side for Django Rest projects, please share your ideas or references.

Comment: see `print(sortParameter)` I think you get string which looks like JSON so you have to use `json.loads(sortParameter)` to convert it into Python object - list/dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, I can not use the print function when deployed Django project in pycharm IDE

Comment: run Django server manually in console/termial and see what it display. Or write value in log or in temporary file. Then you can see text in log/file.

Comment: You don't have to print it, it IS JSON that comes as a string which you have to deserialize. Not sure how to do that in python, but I guess furas has it right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem, but left some things. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more elegant solution, by I just intercept all ajax requests and convert `sort` parameter to DRF-friendly `ordering`:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function (conn, options) {
    if(options.params && options.params.sort) {
        var ordering = options.params.ordering ? options.params.ordering.split(',') : [];
        var sortArray = JSON.parse(options.params.sort);
        sortArray.forEach(function(el){
            ordering.push((el.direction == 'DESC' ? '-' : '') + el.property);
        });
        options.params.ordering = ordering.join(',');
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using json package. Thanks for the advice ***furas***

```
def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Products.objects.all()
        sortParameter = self.request.query_params.get('sort', None)
        parsed_sort=json.loads(sortParameter)
        column_name=parsed_sort[0]['property']

        queryset = queryset.order_by(column_name)
        return queryset
```

But I think the code is not optimal? What is the best practice: build url on backend side  then send a request to the server and the server to do a minimum number of operations to retrieve the request parameters. Or parse request parameters on the server side.